# What is List[String~Int]?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

While going through the scala documentation ([Play Docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAnorm)) of the play framework I saw a syntax I have never seen before.

```
val populations:List[String~Int] = {
  SQL("select * from Country").as( str("name") ~ int("population") * ) 
}
```

Could someone please tell me what does **"~"** in `List[String~Int]` mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

May be this willl help:

```
scala> class ~[A, B]
defined class $tilde

scala> List.empty[String~Int]
res1: List[~[String,Int]] = List()
```

Actually, `~` is not a part of the standard library, this is a generic class from the play framework, which allows an infix notation. In scala, any generic class that takes 2 generic parameters can be use with an infix notation. for example, the following also works:

```
scala> class X[A, B]
defined class X

scala> List.empty[String X Int]
res1: List[X[String,Int]] = List()
```

In your case, you will find the definition of `~` in the [Play framework API](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#anorm.$tilde).

Comment: Actually, it's not a Play class. It comes from the Scala standard library (specifically, the parser combinators library). Here is [the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$tilde).

Comment: Are you sure abourt that? To me it seems that there is two distinct similar classes, but i'm not familiar enough with play2 to know which one they're using.

Comment: @Nicolas sorry, you're right. Here are the [method](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/SqlParser.scala#L95) and [case class](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/main/scala/SqlParser.scala#L49). Anorm's `SqlStatementParser` uses standard parser combinators, so I just assumed that `ResultSetParser` would as well.